# Passing parameters with multiple objects

Tags: list, object, parameter-passing

So what I want to do is pass in an object list, but I have many different ones. (Swords, Chestplates etc). How can I pass in multiple objects to the parameter?

`ListToSave = testObject.ChestPlateList;` that part below is the part I want to pass the object list into.

```
public void DeserializeFromXML(List<ChestPlate> ListToSave, string filepath)
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameObjectData));
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open);
            XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);

            if (!reader.EOF)
            {
                GameObjectData testObject = (GameObjectData)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
                ListToSave = testObject.ChestPlateList;
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", testObject.ChestPlateList);             
            }        
        }
```

Comment: Do 'Swords' and 'Chestplates' inherit from the same parent?

Comment: Yes it is, it all inherits from "GameObject".

Comment: So why not pass `List<GameObject>`?

Comment: I'm getting this error. 

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DatabaseTest.GameObjects>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DatabaseTest.ChestPlate>'

Comment: Try with an interface instead of inherit, and only use the methods provided by the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested)

```
public void SerializeToXML(GameObjectData theData, string filepath)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(theData));
    TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filepath);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, ListToSave);
}
```

and

```
public GameObjectData DeserializeFromXML(string filepath)
{
    GameObjectData result = null;
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameObjectData));
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open);
    XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);

    if (!reader.EOF)
    {
        result = (List<GameObject>)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", result.ChestPlateList);              
    }   
    return result;     
}
```

Comment: it has to be "GameObjectData" which holds the lists for the objects.

Why I use "GameObjectData" for testObject.